# Servo motor duty cycle to angle

Tags: motor, pwm, servo, duty-cycle

I am trying to control a servo motor using a square signal with a varying duty cycle. The data sheet of the motor says that the frequency of the signal should be 20 ms.

In addition, if I need to command it to 0°, I need to give a 1.5 ms/20 ms = 7.5% duty cycle. For 90°, I need: 2 ms/20 ms = 10% (the same for -90°, 1/20 = 5%). So, in order to convert the duty cycle to angles (ms to angles), I did the following:

1. The center is 1.5 ms. I have 0.5 ms for each 90° so each degree will be equal to 0.5/90 ms/degree.

However, when I try to apply this formula to produce the signal, the motor is not turning as it should be. For example, for 45°, it is turning to 25°.

The servo used is a HS-53 from HiTec. I believe the datasheet that was given to me is wrong.

What do you suggest?

Comment: If you think your datasheet is wrong, have you searched for the correct datasheet for your servo?

Comment: The datasheet I found for it had 60 degrees per 600us pulse. With center on 1500us. Which data sheet you are using?

Comment: Yes I think you are right all: I am using this one: https://multiplex-cs.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/00045_HS-53_01-2.pdf

I have found another one that says 40 degree/ 400us https://www.hiteccs.com/public/uploads/data_sheet/HS-53-DataSheet-1642817901.pdf

Thank you guys!!!